# Earliest presentation of a 3-D permutahedron?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Below is a picture of a  3-D permutahedron sundial by Stefano Buonsignori (16th century) in the Medici collection presented by [Museo Galileo](http://brunelleschi.imss.fi.it/museum/esim.asp?c=403055). The permutahedra / permutohedra and the closely related associahedra are important families of convex polytopes.

What is the earliest known presentation of the 3-Dim permutahedron?

[image: Sundial]

Comment: Originally it was known as an Archimedean solid and more specifically as a truncated octahedron, so probably it would be better to ask or search for these names.